# Does @Assert\Choice(callback="...") work only with form builder?

Tags: symfony4

I want restrict values in the field `action`. Only pre-defined strings may be stored in this field. Does `@Assert\Choice(callback="getActions")` work only with form builder?
Is there an another way to check allowed values?

```
class Log
{
    const SENT_REGISTRATION_EMAIL = 'Registration email was sent';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=50)
     * @Assert\Choice(callback="getActions")
     */
    private $action;

    .
    .
    .

    /**
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public static function getActions(): array
    {
        return [self::SENT_REGISTRATION_EMAIL];
    }
}
```

```
$log = new Log();
$log->setAction(Log::SENT_REGISTRATION_EMAIL);

$this->em->persist($log);
$this->em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the best way but in formType you can use 'constraints' in options array (after field name and propertyType).

Here is an exemple :
    `['constraints' => [
     new NotBlank([
         'message' => 'Please choose a password.',
     ]),
     ]],`